# remove remainder from string in php

Tags: php, math, printing, echo

Simple question. I have this code:

```
total = 41
win   = 48

       echo ($total/$win) * 100 ;
```

printing out

85.416666666667

I need to remove the remainder so it prints out: 85 %.

Comment: Remove the remainder (always round down), or round the result to the nearest integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.ideone.com/7JFkI

```
echo floor(($total/$win) * 100) . '%';
```

Depending on how to want to round the number you may need to replace `floor()` with one of

- `floor()` (9.4 → 9, 9.7 → 9)
- `round()` (9.4 → 9, 9.7 → 10)
- `ceil()` (9.4 → 10, 9.7 → 10)

Comment: Wow, for 3 years. I just met ceil. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [round();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function.

```
<?php
$total = 41;
$win   = 48;

echo round(($total/$win)*100).' %'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

the elegant way would be to use string

```
number_format(float $number, int $decimals, string $dec_point, string $thousands_sep);
```

like this:

```
<?php
$total = 41;
$win   = 48;

echo number_format(($total/$win)*100,0,'.').' %'; 
?>
```

Comment: like this one, but in my case I have to use floor()

Comment: then du so number_format(floor(($total/$win)*100),0,'.',',').' %'; i also added the missing fourth parameter for the number_format funcion. totally forgot that it takes either 2 or 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`floor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) function:

```
echo floor(($total/$win) * 100) ;
```